# Is there a repository engine issue for google cloud datalab on Linux Mint 18.3?

Tags: linux, cloud, linux-mint, google-cloud-datalab

I am getting an error when I try to install google cloud datalab:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
    ...
    Ign:18 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-sylvia/main Translation-en
    Reading package lists... Done
    W: The repository 'http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-sylvia Release' does not have a Release file.
    N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
    N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
    E: Failed to fetch http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists/cloud-sdk-sylvia/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2607:f8b0:4007:803::200e 80]
    E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

$ sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk-datalab
    [sudo] password for ...: 
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    E: Unable to locate package google-cloud-sdk-datalab
```

Does anyone have any ideas?  Has anyone made datalab work with linux mint 18.3?

Comment: Which guide are you following? If you're running this on your local machine, you should first get the sdk, then use the gcloud tool to install datalab. See https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstart.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. You have to install Google SDK directly. Here is the link: [google-cloud-sdk-200.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz](https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-200.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz)

Extract the file, then run `./install.sh` then close the shell, open a **new** shell and run `gcloud init`

Source: [Google Cloud Quickstart for Linux](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-linux)

Answer (score 2):

I followed same steps and faced same problem. So just removed newly added repo from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list` and installed gcloud sdk with simple

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
```

ignoring all steps with repos and keys. And everything works fine.

PS I had Python 2.7 already installed

**EDIT** though this solutions works for basic operations like `gcloud init` I had to additionally follow [Quick Start](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-linux) as mentioned in @kurdtpage answer to make `gcloud components update` and all other components work